# WPF - label location not changing

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Hosting a WPF `Custom Control (Label)` in forms not
changing the position of the `Label`, but it is always displayed at the same position. Please let me know how to set the location for a `Label`.

```
this.aLb.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, 0,30, 180);
this.aLb.Height = 30;
this.aLb.Width = 150;
this.aLb.LabelText = "First WPF application";


System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();
host.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
host.Child = aLb;
this.panel1.Controls.Add(host);

this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(259,216);
```

My exceptation is that label displays at the topleft of the panel.
But label is displayed at the bottom of the panel.

Comment: how to set the margin. There are four elements are there top,left, bottom, right. What does this mean

Comment: Try using grids and stackpanels to set the position of labels and other controls. The only way of changing the position is by setting the appropriate margin. And the power of wpf is in the use of XAML even if its your first application, you should try and use XAML for all the designing and binding logic.

Comment: what is the significane of the DockStyle. When i change the dockstyle.none or left or right. Control position changes

Comment: Dock style is the property of the windows control and not your wpf control, dockstyle left means that your control is fixed from the left end and with a dockstyle of none, your control is free to move anywhere. BTW why are you working on a windows form application with wpf?